# How can I set the multipart boundary with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, multipart, boundary

I'm using this guide to send a multipart POST request to a server with JMeter: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter

In this request there are several parts like a file, some strings and JSON.

The problem is, although I specify the boundary in the "Content type" field, JMeter set whatever it wants and the result is the server (Wildfly 10) correctly rejects the request with a "RESTEASY007500: Could find no Content-Disposition header within part".

Here the request configuration:

[image]

And here the generated request:

[image]

I set "jmeter_is_great" but JMeter generates a random boundary.
Is someone having the same problem? Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I asked how to set the boundary because at the beginning of my test the first error throwed by the server was "RESTEASY007550: Unable to get boundary for multipart".
So I added the "Content type" field, which can contain the boundary value, but that doesn't seem to work.
I was not really interested to set a specific boundary at the beginning.

Now, I found a configuration **which work although without specify the boundary**, maybe someone can find it useful:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To validate if your server is handling invalid boundary using JMeter, unclick `use mulitpart/form-data` in your HTTP Request, set `HTTP Header Manager` with `Content-type: multipart/form-data` and then in your `Body Data` add the following:

```
--pZbVxWMEYBsPH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="linkImage"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

true
--pZbVxWMEYBsPHPpbDCQQBUaAhIlYw0H
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Small.png"
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

Ensure you dont have any Parameters or Files Upload set.

Answer (score -1):

If you are building a multipart request manually make sure that `Use multipart/form data for POST` box is **not checked** under the HTTP Request sampler

[image: JMeter uncheck multipart/form-data]

Assuming it is done you can set your custom boundary using the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) like:

[image: JMeter Header Manager custom multipart boundary]

Comment: I tried both checked and unchecked, it doesn't make any difference